# Как в Qt включить файл данных в исполняемый модуль?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, c++17, данные

Есть файл 001.wav
Его нужно запихнуть внутрь exe (вроде как можно запаковать как-то в RCDATA), а после распаковать.
Как это можно сделать?

Comment: добавьте в проект файл ресурсов(`*.qrc`), а в него пропишите нужные файлы https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html

Comment: @MaximTimakov, а это ведь ответ

Comment: @MaximTimakov можете поподробней описать про "а в него пропишите нужные файлы"? И оформить в виде ответа

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Qt поддерживает [систему ресурсов](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html)

В Qt Creator файл ресурсов создается через меню `Файл -> Создать новый  -> Qt -> файл ресурсов`

[image: new qrc file]

Его так же можно создать в любом текстовом редакторе, так как файл ресурсов представляет собой простой `xml`

В ресурсы можно добавлять любые файлы.

Для доступа к ним в имени файла указывается префикс `:`

```cpp
QFile file(":/myfile.dat");
```

либо с использованием `QUrl`:

```cpp
QFile file(QUrl{"qrc:/myfile.dat"});
```

Для примера разберем следующий файл ресурсов

```xml
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/led">
        <file alias="gray.png">pix/led_gray.png</file>
        <file alias="green.png">pix/led_green.png</file>
        <file alias="red.png">pix/led_red.png</file>
        <file alias="orange.png">pix/led_orange.png</file>
        <file alias="yellow.png">pix/led_yellow.png</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

Файл ресурсов состоит из групп `qresource`, которые имеют префиксы пути

В данном случае у нас одна группа `<qresource prefix="/led">`. Все файлы расположенные в ней будут доступны с префиксом `:/led/`

Файлы прописываются в теге `<file alias="short.name">path/to/file.name</file>`, где

- `alias="short.name"` - псевдоним файла
- `path/to/file.name` - путь к файлу на диске

Разберем запись `<file alias="green.png">pix/led_green.png</file>`

Она создаст ресурс с псевдонимом `green.png` из файла `led_green.png` расположенного в директории `pix`

Данный файл можно будет загрузить используя код вида

```cpp
QPixmap led_green {":/led/green.png"};
```